# C++ vector of object creation error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to give each "Person" object in my program a vector of "Record" objects. However, I'm getting the error: "Record was not declared in this scope" for my vector creation. I have my Record .cpp and .h files in the same src folder. Not sure what's going wrong. Do I have to include Record.h in my Person.h file? Code below:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>



class Person
{

private:

    //id, age, name, and date of Person object creation shall be assigned in constructor. The vector 'log' shall be empty at start. 
    int id; 
    int age; 
    std::string name; 
    std::vector<Record> log;
    time_t t;
    struct tm * timeStruct;

public:
    Person();
    ~Person();

};

#endif // PERSON_H
```

Comment: Where is your include for your `Record` class?

Comment: try add `#include "record.h"` or something alike in your sourcode

Comment: Yeah, you need an include directive

Comment: Add `#include "Record.h"` in Person.h.

Comment: Okay thanks, new to C++ and didn't know you had to include the .h file of the object you're trying to use as the type stored in the vector.

Comment: Yeah, it is a pesky little detail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include "record.h"



class Person
{

private:

    //id, age, name, and date of Person object creation shall be assigned in constructor. The vector 'log' shall be empty at start. 
    int id; 
    int age; 
    std::string name; 
    std::vector<Record> log;
    time_t t;
    struct tm * timeStruct;

public:
    Person();
    ~Person();

};

#endif // PERSON_H
```

This should do it for you